# javascript error - Scripts are not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var path = '/Scripts/';
    document.write('<base href="' + path + '"/>');

  </script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>WELCOME</h1>

<script src="test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
console.log("Message from external script");
```

**output**

[error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTUpu.png)

Here you can see, first it try to load the script from body tag before it get the actual base href path from script section.

Is there any way to get come out from this error? I mean not to load body script until base href set.

Once the base href set, it executed successfully.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you dynamically add the script tags using javascript, instead of markdown?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing is (somewhat) browser-specific, and is related to your use of `document.write` to set the base href dynamically.

Chrome and Firefox try to load the page resources before applying the document.write, then updates those urls and tries again after you set the page `<base>`.  Safari appears to not do this; it uses the inserted base href immediately.  I have not tested other browsers.

(In all browsers the `<base>` tag, whether static or dynamic, needs to appear in the document before any links that depend on it.)

Other than the extra network request this seems to be harmless (see below), but you could avoid it by using a static `<base>` tag instead of dynamically writing one in, or by setting the full path on the `<script>` tag instead of depending on the `<base>`.

(re "harmless":  I checked the case where a test.js exists both at the root level and inside the "/Scripts" directory.  Dynamically inserting the "/Scripts/" base href did *not* cause both scripts to execute in Chrome: successful network requests for both test.js files were made, but only the code in "/Scripts/" was executed. So the browser makers have handled that edge case already. Good job, browser makers!)

Answer (score -1):

You Can use this code

```
<script src="./scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: './Scripts/' is coming from backend. I can't hard coded it.